# Reusable Method to change gridview cell colour

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to change the colour of gridview cells based on the data value. I can quite easily do this using a datarow view in the Gridviews RowDataBound Event and an if statement (see below), however I need to do this on 30 columns which will be rather long winded and a pain to change if the business rules change. How can I encapsulate the following into a reusable method that I can call and just pass in the data column and the cell index ?

```
    protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            int A = Int32.Parse(drv["A"].ToString());
            if (A <= 74)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would look at creating an enum of Colors to be set then based on the conditions. replace system.Drawing.Color.Red with an enum.color drv would have to be changed as well or would would have to have an array or List or enum created that could also determine which fields are to be changed ..even if it were .config driven.. what are some of the business rules for example..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void SetColor(DataGridViewRow row, string columnName, int cellIndex)
{
    var data = (GridViewRow)row.DataItem;
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(data[columnName]);
    if (number > 74) return;

    row.Cells[cellIndex].BackColor = Color.Red;
}

protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataRowType.DataRow) return;
    SetColor(e, "A", 2);
}
```

Comment: I would add the color as parameter to the method as well, at least because that's it's name ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter ther is a lot that can be done to refactor this code into something reusable. it all depends on how much reuse is expected. given the context of the post and the current code I figured this was the most applicable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - Mr Meckley put me on the right track and my working (if inelegant) solution is:

```
    public void SetColor2(GridViewRow row, string columnName, int cellIndex)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(columnName);
            if (number == 0)
            {
                row.Cells[cellIndex].Text = "";
                return;
            }
            else if ((number > 0) && (number <= 74))
            {
                row.Cells[cellIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                row.Cells[cellIndex].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    protected void gv1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            SetColor2(e.Row, drv["A"].ToString(), 2);
            SetColor2(e.Row, drv["B"].ToString(), 3);
            etc...
        }
    }
```